# PHP/Oracle - OCI doesn't like my data type?

Tags: php, oracle, oracle12c, oracle-call-interface, datagrip

I'm new to OCI, but just trying to do a basic oci_bind_by_name in PHP to get it working. But even with a simple select statement and a dummy variable, it rejects the variable type.

Here's the code:

```
$conn = oci_connect($username, $password, $database);
$dummy = "dummy@dummy.com";
$u = oci_parse($conn, "select ca_email from pwv_google_group");
oci_bind_by_name($u, ':ca_email', $dummy);
```

But it just returns:

```
Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

Since this is a very simple query/parameter, I can only assume my syntax is wrong or something might be off on the Oracle side (ca_email really should be a varchar, but I'm using Datagrip which doesn't allow DESC command, so I don't know how to validate that). Is something else wrong?

Comment: Try replacing the dash  (`-`) with an underscore (`_`)

Comment: Note: there is no parameter in your query: `select ca_email from pwv_google_group`, so what does `':ca-email'` stands for?

Comment: You're right, I wasn't binding in the query too. looks like that's what was missing, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`oci_bind_by_name()` is expecting you to bind a value for some form of input to the SQL statement - from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php)

> **bv_name** The colon-prefixed bind variable placeholder used in the
>   statement. The colon is optional in **bv_name**. Oracle does not use
>   question marks for placeholders.

So for your example, it would be more like

```
$u = oci_parse($conn, "select * from pwv_google_group where ca_email = :ca_email");
oci_bind_by_name($u, ':ca_email', $dummy);
```

As you are trying to retrieve the values from the data you just need to fetch the data as in (hacked from example #3 in manual)

```
$u = oci_parse($conn, 'select ca_email from pwv_google_group');
oci_execute($u);
$row = oci_fetch_array($u, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
foreach ($row as $item) {
    print $item."<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you're a genius. I hadn't realized that I needed to bind in the statement too.  it's happy now!